# How to publish to nuget.org using Octopus Deploy?

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy

I would love to use Octopus Deploy to allow us to publish to nuget.org. I "assume" the following workflow.

- Bundle the nuspec that is to be published to nuget.org (myapp.nupkg)
- Bundle the above nupkg along side a build.ps1 script for Octopus to run (toPublish.nupkg)
- Deploy the "toPublish.nupkg" locally and run the build.ps1 script

The build.ps1 script does the API publish to nuget.org
http://www.dzone.com/articles/using-powershell-publish-nuget

Does this sound about right, or am I way off base?

If this sounds right, what do I do about the API key for nuget.org? Obviously I can't put it in a Github repo, does Octopus have a way to handle variables in powershell?

*Current version of Octopus: 1.6.2.1722*

Comment: I did try putting a nupkg file inside the nuspec `<file src="somefile.nupkg" target="content" />` but when I build, nothing shows up. I think there' s some safeguard built into nuget.

Comment: [Added as a feature request](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/5865596-simple-way-to-publish-nupkg-files-to-nuget-org) for clean built-in integration.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically I *think* you could publish a nuget package to nuget.org just using the OctoPack as it allows you to specify an API key and a url to push to. That's what that powershell script is effectively doing; creating nuget packages and pushing them to a URL with an API key.

Granted, I'm also assuming you're using TFS so that's a poor assumption on my part. If you don't want to use the OctoPack (or can't), you could also use the powershell script as you provided.

For variables however, Octopus can definitely do that, however for version 1.6, I'm not 100% sure how extensive the variables feature is as I have barely any experience with version 1.6. I'm much more familiar with 2.0+.

So for 2.0+, within the Variables tab of your project, you can supply variable names to use within powershell scripts (and reference using #{*variablename*}). Check out the official documentation here: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variables.

Keep in mind too, that with 2.0, there's an option to mark your variables as "sensitive" so they're encrypted within RavenDB and hidden from plain sight (only after you save!). Once the value is in the variables tab as 'sensitive', you can never see the value from within the Octopus UI. Again, I think this is a 2.0+ feature so using 1.6 may not have this available.

I would recommend upgrading to the 2.0+ version of Octopus if possible as their [roadmap](http://octopusdeploy.com/roadmap) has a huge number of features coming out and at very aggressive pace as well.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply. We are looking to upgrade to 2.4 when it goes release. We're using Gitblit and TeamCity for our repo and build system (not TFS). So you're saying I don't need to bundle the nupkg inside the nupkg? How does this "OctoPack" work? Note our nupkg is already build and dropped in the build_artifacts folder in TeamCity.

Comment: I'll address your question in two parts. The OctoPack is a *build*-time included dll for solutions using MSBuild. You can simply install the OctoPack via NuGet. The OctoPack (when enabled) can automatically create all the nuget packages in your solution (assuming they have the nuspec file present), and push said generated packages to a URL along with the API key. I'm not sure if the OctoPack can work with TeamCity as I've never used it before, but check out the documentation here: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack.

Comment: As far as bundling the nuget package inside another package, you don't need to do that unless you're trying to do something that I'm unaware of. Octopus can deploy as many nuget packages as you want, however they may not all happen within the same step. What's your solution for? .NET site? App? Service? Azure? Maybe there's an easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I misunderstood. I read your post again. So you're trying to bundle a nuget package for Octopus deployments exclusively inside of your host package for nuget.org? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: that's correct. I have an OSS project on [Github](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/AppCore.Data) that is destined for [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FutureState.AppCore.Data/). I want to simplify our release stuff by integrating Octopus rather than manually downloading the artifact and then manually uploading it. Also since we don't want every build on Nuget, We don't want to hook it into the build step on TeamCity.

Comment: Octopus by default doesn't directly integrate with TFS/TeamCity/whatever CI solution so no need to worry. You're essentially trying to bundle build.ps1 script into your host nuget package (myapp.nupkg) into a final package for nuget.org (toPublish.nupkg). I think I got it. :P

Can't you just include that powershell script into your solution as it's not called predeploy.ps1, deploy.ps1 or postdeploy.ps1?

Then within Octopus you're just running a powershell script that packs your solution and sends it off to nuget.org. Yeah, this is perfectly achievable although I've never done it.

Comment: sounds about right. I originally tried bundling the nupkg (for nuget.org) inside the nupkg that octopus tries to deploy. Unfortunately there's some safeguard build into nuget.exe that prevents nesting nupkg's. I need to figure out a different way... just not sure how, nor am I confident I know how to best leverage octopus.

Comment: You've got the right idea for Octopus. I know that Octopus will be changing how it deals with powershell scripts in nested solutions: http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/rfc-root-most-scripts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51775/discussion-between-osij2is-and-chase-florell)